# Can I develop with GreenDAO on Linux?

Tags: java, android, linux, greendao

I would like to learn GreenDAO, and was wondering if I could play around with it on Linux, or do I need a full Android SDK environment/emulator/ide in order to just use it?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need full Android SDK environment/emulator/ide. But yes you should be having Java installed in your system.

Happy Coding..